# stream camera ip emgucv

Tags: c#, emgucv

Hello when i run this code to c# with emgucv to see a live ip camera in a picturebox it show me an error
in this part:

```
Mat frame = new Mat();
_capture.Retrieve(frame, 0);
captureImageBox.Image = frame;
```

the error mentions

> Cannot convert a type emgu.cv.mat in emgu.cv.imag...

What lines of code do i need to change to run it correctly....

**Specs**

- Visual studio 2015
- emgucv v3.1 x64

  ```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
  private Capture _capture = null;
  private bool _captureInProgress;
  public Form1()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      CvInvoke.UseOpenCL = false;
      try
      {
          _capture = new Capture("http://webcam.st-malo.com/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?");
          _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
      }
      catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
      }
  }

  private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
  {
      Mat frame = new Mat();
      _capture.Retrieve(frame, 0);

      captureImageBox.Image = frame;

  }

  private void captureButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (_capture != null)
      {
          if (_captureInProgress)
          {  //stop the capture
              captureButton.Text = "Start Capture";
              _capture.Pause();
          }
          else
          {
              //start the capture
              captureButton.Text = "Stop";
              _capture.Start();
          }

          _captureInProgress = !_captureInProgress;
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: You need to convert the `Mat` to an `image` data type using `ToImage` (http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/8e55d304-16cb-c8a1-bb1b-702cb567a069.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing Mat to Image
using this

```
Mat frame = new Mat();
_capture.Retrieve(frame, 0);

captureImageBox.Image = frame.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
```